# How to Return Json Format data in .Net core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my dotnet core project return the mongodb data like bellow

Actual Result:

```
{
"obj":{
"value": "[{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5c67fbdeacb7e0d82daab871\"), \"name\" : \"NewPatient\", \"description\" : \"\", \"targeturl\" : \"http://sub.domain.in", \"active\" : true, \"createddate\" : ISODate(\"2019-02-16T06:10:20.201Z\"),{ \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"5c67fbdeacb7e0d82daab870\"), \"name\" : \"NewPatient\", \"description\" : \"\", \"targeturl\" : \"http://sub.domain.in", \"active\" : true, \"createddate\" : ISODate(\"2019-02-16T06:10:20.201Z\")]"
},
"value": 1,
"info": " Retrived Successfully"
}
```

But Expected Result is

```
{
"obj":{
"value": [{ "_id" :"5c67fbdeacb7e0d82daab871), "name" : "NewPatient", "description" : "", "targeturl" : "http://sub.domain.in", "active" : true, "createddate" : "2019-02-16T06:10:20.201",{ "_id" : "5c67fbdeacb7e0d82daab870", "name" : "NewPatient", "description" : "", "targeturl" : "http://sub.domain.in", "active" : true, "createddate" : "2019-02-16T06:10:20.201Z"}]
},
"value": 1,
"info": " Retrived Successfully"
}
```

How to do it. My code is like below

```
var doc = Collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToEnumerable();
report.Add("value",doc.ToJson());
returnData.Add("obj",report);
returnData.Add("value",1);
returnData.Add("info","Reports Retrived Successfully");
```

Please any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Comment: What about `return Json(yourData)` ?

Comment: Thanks @TanvirArjel . I am getting this error The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Is it not an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: It is a .Net Core Api

Comment: try `return Ok(youData)` and let me know!

Comment: same data format is returning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188681/discussion-between-satheesh-p-and-tanvirarjel).

Comment: Please check the chat